# Recursive function to return a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, file, recursion, directory

I have the tree of above. I need to search in a recursive way the directories and files from the tree and return them as a dictionary in the following form ->
key: directories/name of file  and  value: first line of file

```
eg: key:1/2/5/test5    value:first line of test 5
```

[image]

So far, i created the next code:

```
def search(root):
    items = os.listdir(root)
    
    for element in items:
        if os.path.isfile(element):
        
            with open (element) as file:
                one_line=file.readline()
                print(one_line)

        elif os.path.isdir(element):
            search(os.path.join(root,element))
```

The problem is that my code only searches the directories. Please make me understand where i'm wrong and how to solve it. Massive appreciation for any help, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean `my code only searches the directories`? Why don't you use a dictionary to save file information before printing one_line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. It has to be adjusted a little, though.
More specifically,

1. `element` is a file or directory **name** (not path). If it is a subdirectory or file in a subdirectory the value of `if os.path.isfile(element)` and `elif os.path.isdir(element)` will be always *False*. Hence, replace them with `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, element))` and `elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, element))` respectively.
2. Similarly, `with open(element)` should be replaced by `with open(os.path.join(root,element))`.
3. When reading the file's first line, you have to store the path and that line in a dictionary.
4. That dictionary has to be updated when calling the recursive function in `elif os.path.isdir(element)`.

See below for the complete snippet:

```py
import os

def search(root):

    my_dict = {}   # this is the final dictionary to be populated

    for element in os.listdir(root):
        
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, element)):
            try: 
                with open(os.path.join(root, element)) as file:
                    my_dict[os.path.join(root, element)] = file.readline() # populate the dictionary
            except UnicodeDecodeError: 
                # This exception handling has been put here to ignore decode errors (some files cannot be read)
                pass

        elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, element)):
            my_dict.update(search(os.path.join(root,element)))  # update the current dictionary with the one resulting from the recursive call

    return my_dict

print(search('.'))
```

It prints a dictionary like below:

```
{
 "path/file.csv": "name,surname,grade",
 "path/to/file1.txt": "this is the first line of file 1",
 "path/to/file2.py": "import os"
}
```

For the sake of readability, `os.path.join(root, element)` can be stored in a variable, then:

```py
import os

def search(root):

    my_dict = {}   # this is the final dictionary to be populated

    for element in os.listdir(root):
        path = os.path.join(root, element)

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            with open(path) as file:
                my_dict[path] = file.readline()

        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            my_dict.update(search(path))

    return my_dict

print(search('.'))
```

Comment: You have an upvote from me. The problem was..as you said... with the `os.path.join(root, element)`  for `os.path.isdir`  and `os.path.isfile`. Can you tell me why it is needed to make the join for every isfile and isdir? I want to learn and write that is my logbook. Please make me understand or send me a link with the information.

Comment: In your tree, you start the search at directory where only "1" is present. Therefore, through the recursive calls, element will be "1", then "2", then "5", then "test5" and so on so forth. Obviously, they are NOT recognized as files and directory since they are not in the current directory. Using the join, element will be "./1", then "1/2" (second recursive call), then "1/2/5" (at the third recursive call), and finally "1/2/5/test5". That is, you can access subdirectories and files

Comment: Please, if that solves your problem mark the answer as "accepted"

Answer (score 1):

You can use **os.walk**

The following function will not include empty folders.

```
def get_tree(startpath):
    tree = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        for file in files:
            path = root+"/"+file
            with open(path,'r') as f:
                first_line =  f.readline()
            tree[path] = first_line
    return tree
```

The output will be like this:

```
{
    file_path : first_line_of_the_file,
    file_path2 : first_line_of_the_file2,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!:) The idea of using `os.walk()` was my second option. I really wanted to create a recursive function to search directories, but if i won't find a solution, i will try to use os.walk().